# similarity score between vectors and creating column vectors based on a function

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a sample on which I want to create an aggregate measure based on similarity scores of the person's movie interests. For example consider the following data.

```
person <- c( 'John', 'John', 'Vikram', 'Kris', 'Kris', 'Lara', 'Mohi', 'Mohi', 'Mohi')

year<- c(2010, 2011,2010,2010, 2011, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2012)
sciencefiction <- c( 4, 5, 0, 44,32, 5, 32, 43,33)
romantic <- c( 19, 28, 56, 7, 4, 33, 2,1,2)
comedy<- c(22,34, 22,34,44, 54, 54,32,44)
timespent<- c(30,40, 100,33, 22, 80, 96, 22,34)
df<- data.frame(person, year, sciencefiction, romantic, comedy, timespent)
```

I want to variable called similarity score which is basically given by the sum of a persons[i] distance from person[j] multiplied by the time spent by j and is summed over all the combinations for one year. For example for person John for year 2010 it would be

```
 score[john, 2010]= 0.8 * 100+ 0.6 * 33+ .98 * 80 + .73* 96 = 248.28
```

The 0.8 is the distance (cosine distance calculated by a.b/|a| |b|) between the john and vikram determined by the cosine angle (as shown above) between two vectors formed by sciencefiction+ romantic+comedy (see here (v[i] = 4i+19j+22k and v[j]= 0i+7j+34k)) and 100 is the time spent by Vikram in watching the movies in 2010. In a similar way the comparisons are made and aggregated for John. Is there a way I do this operation in R to create a row called score with the above procedure? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `df$score <- with(df, 0.8*timespent + 0.6*sciencefiction ...)`? (fill in the `...` with the rest of your formula). This solution takes advantage of vectorized calculations, a much faster and (IMHO) cleaner approach instead of row-by-row processing. (BTW: your example does not seem consistent with your data, so it's hard to give you an answer that meets your expected output.)

Comment: the data is correct. 0.8 is the angle between two vectors formed by v[i] = 4i+19j+22k and v[j]= 0i+7j+34k which gives 0.8 as the angle or distance between Vikram and John and then I multiply the value with time spent by Vikram which is 100 hrs. does it makes sense?

Comment: Sort of. I see 4, 9, 22 are John. However, 0 is Vikram but 7, 34 are Kris. But I think I get your point.

Comment: To find the angle b/w two vectors, I'm using the [geometric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) and solving for theta. Using your two vectors (`4,19,22` and `0,7,34`), I get `cos(theta) = 0.865`, so `theta = 0.526`. Even if I use data from the question (`4,19,22` and `0,56,22`), I get `theta = 0.502`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry i meant i used the distance is basically cosine(theta) value and not the theta value, i.e.,  I used .8 (~.865) for calculating the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll step through this solution. Skip down to the bottom for the overall result.

Up front: because 2012 only has one person (`Mohi`), there is no output. You can easily capture this either by not filtering out self-comparisons (which should score 0) or re-merging in missing person/year rows.

**Update 2**: your `df$person` needs to be `character`, so either create your data with

```
df <- data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

or modify it in-place with

```
df$person <- as.character(df$person)
```

#### Dependencies

I'm using `dplyr` here primarily because I think it clearly communicates what is going on. There is nothing in the code that could not be replaced with base functions (or even `data.table`).

```
library(dplyr)
```

One could use `tidyr::crossing` instead of `expand.grid` and `purrr::pmap` instead of `mapply`. They have strengths but are mostly drop-in replacements, so I leave it up to the reader.

A simple [geometric angle-calculation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition), for simplicity/reference

```
angle <- function(a, b, zero = NaN) {
  num <- (a %*% b)
  denom <- sqrt(sum(a^2)) * sqrt(sum(b^2))
  if (denom == 0) zero else (num / denom)
}
```

**Update**: if either of the vectors is all-`0`, then R calculates `0/0` as `NaN`. Depending on your use, it may make sense to change this to `0` or `NA`.

#### Identify unique combinations (not permutations)

```
df %>%
  distinct(year, person) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  do( expand.grid(person = .$person, person2 = .$person, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(person != person2) %>%
  mutate(
    p1 = pmin(person, person2),
    p2 = pmax(person, person2)
  ) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  select(-person, -person2)
# # A tibble: 13 × 3
#     year    p1     p2
#    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>
# 1   2010  John Vikram
# 2   2010  John   Kris
# 3   2010  John   Lara
# 4   2010  John   Mohi
# 5   2010  Kris Vikram
# 6   2010  Lara Vikram
# 7   2010  Mohi Vikram
# 8   2010  Kris   Lara
# 9   2010  Kris   Mohi
# 10  2010  Lara   Mohi
# 11  2011  John   Kris
# 12  2011  John   Mohi
# 13  2011  Kris   Mohi
```

If you did up through (but stopping at) the `expand.grid`, you'd end up with redundant pairs, e.g. "John, Vikram" and "Vikram, John". Because I'm inferring you are interested in pairwise [*combinations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) vice [*permutations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), the rest of that code block removes redundant rows.

#### Bring in each person's data

(continuing in the pipe with the previous data)

```
... %>%
  left_join(setNames(df, paste0(colnames(df), "1")), by = c("p1" = "person1", "year" = "year1")) %>%
  left_join(setNames(df, paste0(colnames(df), "2")), by = c("p2" = "person2", "year" = "year2"))
# # A tibble: 13 × 11
#     year    p1     p2 sciencefiction1 romantic1 comedy1 timespent1 sciencefiction2 romantic2 comedy2 timespent2
#    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1   2010  John Vikram               4        19      22         30               0        56      22        100
# 2   2010  John   Kris               4        19      22         30              44         7      34         33
# 3   2010  John   Lara               4        19      22         30               5        33      54         80
# 4   2010  John   Mohi               4        19      22         30              32         2      54         96
# 5   2010  Kris Vikram              44         7      34         33               0        56      22        100
# 6   2010  Lara Vikram               5        33      54         80               0        56      22        100
# 7   2010  Mohi Vikram              32         2      54         96               0        56      22        100
# 8   2010  Kris   Lara              44         7      34         33               5        33      54         80
# 9   2010  Kris   Mohi              44         7      34         33              32         2      54         96
# 10  2010  Lara   Mohi               5        33      54         80              32         2      54         96
# 11  2011  John   Kris               5        28      34         40              32         4      44         22
# 12  2011  John   Mohi               5        28      34         40              43         1      32         22
# 13  2011  Kris   Mohi              32         4      44         22              43         1      32         22
```

#### Calculate the angle per pair

```
... %>%
  mutate(
    angle = mapply(function(a,b,c, d,e,f) angle(c(a,b,c), c(d,e,f), zero=NA),
                   sciencefiction1, romantic1, comedy1,
                   sciencefiction2, romantic2, comedy2, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
  ) %>%
select(year, p1, p2, starts_with("timespent"), angle)
# A tibble: 13 × 6
#     year    p1     p2 timespent1 timespent2     angle
#    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1   2010  John Vikram         30        100 0.8768294
# 2   2010  John   Kris         30         33 0.6427461
# 3   2010  John   Lara         30         80 0.9851037
# 4   2010  John   Mohi         30         96 0.7347653
# 5   2010  Kris Vikram         33        100 0.3380778
# 6   2010  Lara Vikram         80        100 0.7948679
# 7   2010  Mohi Vikram         96        100 0.3440492
# 8   2010  Kris   Lara         33         80 0.6428056
# 9   2010  Kris   Mohi         33         96 0.9256539
# 10  2010  Lara   Mohi         80         96 0.7881070
# 11  2011  John   Kris         40         22 0.7311130
# 12  2011  John   Mohi         40         22 0.5600843
# 13  2011  Kris   Mohi         22         22 0.9533073
```

#### Finally, the score

```
... %>%
  group_by(year, person = p1) %>%
  summarize(
    score = angle %*% timespent2
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 × 3
#    year person     score
#   <dbl>  <chr>     <dbl>
# 1  2010   John 258.23933
# 2  2010   Kris 174.09501
# 3  2010   Lara 155.14507
# 4  2010   Mohi  34.40492
# 5  2011   John  28.40634
# 6  2011   Kris  20.97276
```

I'm guessing the difference between my 258.24 and your 248.28 is due to the second vector (`Vikram`'s values).

#### TL;DR

All at once:

```
df %>%
  distinct(year, person) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  do( expand.grid(person = .$person, person2 = .$person, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(person != person2) %>%
  mutate(
    p1 = pmin(person, person2),
    p2 = pmax(person, person2)
  ) %>%
  select(-person, -person2) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  # p-wise lookups
  left_join(setNames(df, paste0(colnames(df), "1")), by = c("p1" = "person1", "year" = "year1")) %>%
  left_join(setNames(df, paste0(colnames(df), "2")), by = c("p2" = "person2", "year" = "year2")) %>%
  # calc angles
  mutate(
    angle = mapply(function(a,b,c, d,e,f) angle(c(a,b,c), c(d,e,f)),
                   sciencefiction1, romantic1, comedy1,
                   sciencefiction2, romantic2, comedy2, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  # calc scores
  group_by(year, person = p1) %>%
  summarize(
    score = angle %*% timespent2
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: I got this error. Error: could not find function "angle" Please advise

Comment: I was able to correct that error. Thanks so much. I  got this error Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  dims [product 1] do not match the length of object [954]

Comment: there are some NaN values occuring as there are 0 values in some vectors, is there a way to remove them

Comment: That's happening withing `angle`, when it ultimately tries `0/0`. What makes better sense there, `0` or `NA`? (See my edit, you can define whatever `0/0` should be for your needs.)

Comment: thanks! for some reason i am not able to see the output, i am getting an error like this, Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  dims [product 1] do not match the length of object [954]

Comment: Sorry, it works for me without error (obviously, otherwise I wouldn't have posted it :-). It's like that you have more noise in your data than I have in this sample data. I suggest you start subsetting your data to find what works and what doesn't, then try to find the unique problems with the bad subsets. From there, you can run incrementally-larger parts of the calc pipe to see where things go wrong.

Comment: ok that makes sense, I mean how to see the output, the output is written as "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame", how do i extract them as dataframe. Thanks so much for your awesome solution!!

Comment: it worked for me as well ;) the onlything is i cannot make it a dataframe so i ca run some statistics!

Comment: Perhaps change the first line to `x <- df %>%` to capture the results of the whole pipe into `x`. Is that what you meant? (The "shell script" equivalent of dplyr's `out <- func1() %>% func2() %>% func3` is `out=$(func1 | func2 | func3)`; newlines after each `%>%` are solely for code organization.

Comment: Thanks so much! for some reason I am not able to replicate your exact same results. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I used the same data and in the first step I am not getting the same output as yours, am i missing anything? i tried the whole thing and i was getting the scores for john as 30, have you changed the data? is there some steps i am missing.

Comment: I am getting two columns of John with 30 for 2010 and 40 for 2011. Please advise.

Comment: Oops, edited that out while writing this up. Need your data to be `character` not `factor`, so change to `df <- data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` or use `df$person <- as.character(df$person)`.

Comment: yes i corrected that, i am getting the results till the second step and last steps it is blanking out, i am missing anything. says no sciencefiction1 found using the [all at once] code, please suggest

Comment: it is working my friend! thanks, i am getting the same results as output! the only thing is i am not able to capture the output!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144013/discussion-between-r2evans-and-user3570187).